# Parsing a unicode text file in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, parsing, unicode, text-files

I am trying to parse through a file and grab little bits of relevant data. My method worked but I had a suspicion it was weak. Testing on multiple files confirmed it. The files are PDF's mostly generated by Adobe Illustrator on Macs. When I open the files in Notepad there is a lot of encoded crap but otherwise all the data I want is human-readable ASCII stuff. In Notepad my test file is 241 lines long, Macintosh(CR) ANSI. I knew something was up when I parsed out the file and it recognized only 21 lines. Still, it worked. On larger files it fails silently. I believe because the lines pulled are longer than the instr() function can handle so it returns 0. There's a lot of trapping and de-bug in the example but the basic method for getting lines is there. Nothing on-line indicates there's options for Open For Input but I'm hoping.

```
    iRowNumber = 4
    Open sReadFileName For Input As #1
    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sNextLine
        If iLineInc < 33 Then
            Response = MsgBox("Line : " & iLineInc & ":" & sNextLine, 0)
        End If
        LocationResult = InStr(sNextLine, sFindString)
        If LocationResult > 0 Then
            Response = MsgBox("Swatch Found : " & iLineInc & ":" & LocationResult, 0)
            While LocationResult > 0
                ElementStart = LocationResult
                StartCut = InStr(ElementStart, sNextLine, """") + 1
                EndCut = InStr(StartCut, sNextLine, """") - 1
                sColorName = Mid(sNextLine, StartCut, (EndCut - StartCut) + 1)......
```

Is there a way to get the `Open sReadFileName for Input` to recognize the different type line separators? It's obviously a mix as the first 5 or 6 lines read as they appear in Notepad but then the next 150 or so are one line.

I get the impression FSO is a better tool. However, it doesn't work on my laptop due to missing dll's or security settings. I have to assume my potential users would have the same issues and cannot alter the application or Windows system.

Tried FSO but "ActiveX control cannot create object." tried to slowly digest the lines with `split()` function but that fails silently as well. Fails to execute functions on a string, assuming because it's just too long.

Comment: I certainly agree on the bloated nature of PDF. I was hoping there was some work around but it appears NotePad has some more code that does it's best to translate the streams of characters into a human readable form.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution by looking at a bunch of online sources. FileSystem Objects were ruled out as distributed users may or may not have everything in place to make those work.

Appears I was dealing with two problems. 1.) Files were built with a Line Feed only. 2.) Due to the nature of the massive embedded images and file blocks, there were EOF's in the body of the stream I was parsing through. Open for Input only uses Cr or LfCR to get lines. It would also bag out on the internal EOFs.

Turns out the split() function has the ability to key in on Lf, Cr, or LfCr as the delimiter. Even a 75MB was virtually instant. Looping through the 40k-80k individual strings cut up by the split() takes longer but not horrific.

Opening for Input was tripping on the EOFs. By opening the file as a binary stream based on the length of the file, all that was ignored. Once in memory it can be crammed into a string in it's entirety by Input$(x_number of bytes, input_file_number). Split() with vbLf as the delimiter manages to create a one dimensional array with each element array(n) being a string defined by the original file's Line Feeds. Stepping through the array is basic. I have some debugging message boxes and debug variables in there.

```
Open sReadFileName For Binary As #1
        iInputFileLength = LOF(1)
        ' Response = MsgBox("Length : " & iInputFileLength, 0)
        sChonk = Input$(iInputFileLength, 1)
        'Try with Lf as that's most typical. On fail try Cr.
        iarr = Split(sChonk, vbLf)
        If UBound(iarr) > 0 Then
            sLineDelim = "vbLf"
        Else
            iarr = Split(sChonk, vbCr)
            If UBound(iarr) > 0 Then
                sLineDelim = "vbCr"
            Else
                Response = MsgBox("Negative Ghostrider, the pattern is empty.", 0)
            End If
        End If
    Close #1
    For linenum = 0 To UBound(iarr) - 1
        'Do your line by line stuff here
    Next
```